# Overloading of methods with Type constraints

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I have update function that I'd like to overload according to the input parameter  (whether it is value type or reference type)

```
public void Update<T>(T item) where T : ValueType
```

the compiler has error and it insist I cannot use valuetype (and couple more as a constraint).
should I give up or is there a neat way to overload method according to my desired types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `where T : struct` to enforce that `T` is a non-nullable value type (this *doesn't* work with `Nullable<T>`, despite that being a value type).

However, this won't help your bigger goal, as you can't overload by type constraints - so this is invalid:

```
// Invalid overloading
void Foo<T>(T item) where T : class
void Foo<T>(T item) where T : struct
```

Basically although the *number* of type parameters is part of the signature of the method (in terms of overloading), the names and constraints aren't.

There are [horrible ways round this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/11/02/evil-code-overload-resolution-workaround.aspx), but I'd recommend using different method names instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a value type (non nullable), use a struct:

`public void Update<T>(T item) where T : struct`

Comment: looks promising I'll try - BTW the class is also generic <T>, so when i use the same letter <T> to the generic method the compiler doesn't agree it to be the same letter...weird..

Comment: @user1025852: I don't see anything weird about that. Why would you want to do that? Having two type parameters with the same name (one at the class level, one at the method level) seems a recipe for unreadability...